# How to hide a custom field in wordpress

Tags: wordpress, field

I m working on my website and I'm trying to get custom fields to work. I have a page with some custom fields added. When I add this php code

```
<?php the_meta ?>
```

to my single.php file, a custom field 'WP-Prosper' automatically displayed to my post with its value like this.

```
 WP-Prosper: a:2:{s:12:"remove_thumb";s:0:"";s:11:"video_embed";s:0:"";}
 File Type: .IPA
```

I didn't give any value to this custom field. How can I remove it from my custom field section?

Answer (score 0):

Use [**Delete Custom Fields**](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/delete-custom-fields/) plugin to remove your unwanted custom field.

Or you can manually delete it from `postmeta` table of WordPress database.

Cheers!!!

**UPDATE**

***Manual removal of postmeta from phpmyadmin***

**Important: before updating, please [back up your database](http://codex.wordpress.org/WordPress_Backups) and files.*

1. Go to your database’s phpmyadmin.
2. In the left column look for “wp_postmeta”
3. Click on Browse at the top of the page.
4. Find the Sort by key: drop-down menu and choose “option_name
   (ascending)” or “option_name (descending)”
5. Under the “option_name” column, look for the name of the Custom
   Field that you want want to delete.
6. Click the red X in that row to delete the Custom Field. Repeat for
   each instance of that particular Custom Field you wish to get rid
   of.
7. In WordPress, open up a new post and scroll down to Custom Fields.
   Look in the drop down menu to make sure that Custom Field is now
   gone.

Comment: Thank you Libin, but your plugin Only delete the custom field from published posts. But when I add new post that field comes again. I don't want that custom field any more. Any better solution?

Answer (score 0):

`the_meta()` is perhaps too blunt an instrument: it simply shows *all* custom fields for the post.

You'll have complete control over your output if you specify which meta keys exactly you want to output. Take a look at http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_post_meta

e.g. `<?php echo get_post_meta($post->ID, 'my_meta_key'); ?>`